# Javascript prototype extend base-class unable to access base-class properties/methods from prototype class

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype, base-class, extending

I have created a javascript class **TkpSlider** being inspired from this [w3schools page](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_slideshow.asp). ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jc7hbgw2/2/))

```
var TkpSlider = function (args) {
    args= args|| {};
};

var mainSwiper = new TkpSlider();
```

I have extended this to add some swipe ability being inspired from [this page](http://gilmation.com/articles/javascript-event-delegation-for-a-horizontal-swipe-effect/) so that I can the slider works on user swipe. ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gtc9ocak/1/))

```
var TkpSwiper = function (args) {
    TkpSlider.call(this, args);
};

TkpSwiper.prototype = Object.create(TkpSlider.prototype);

var mainSwiper = new TkpSwiper();
```

I separated the code so I don't get confused later from the base code and if any additional function. But with OOP I have to extend by creating a new name for it **TkpSwiper**, But I want to find another way to use the same name **TkpSlider**.

I saw [this article](https://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/using-the-javascript-prototype-property-to-structure-and-extend-code) and tried to use prototype to extend **TkpSlider** in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gtc9ocak/2/) (Snippet below). The problem is I can't access the public methods of the base class from child class. The sample javascript in the blog I tested working though, I must be missing something with my code. Could anyone shed some insight? Thanks.

```js
var TkpSlider = function (args) {
 args= args|| {};
    //private variable
     var btnPrev = args.btnPrev || "tkp-slide-btn-prev";//class for previous button (default: "tkp-slide-btn-prev")
    var btnNext = args.btnNext || "tkp-slide-btn-next";//class for next button (default: "tkp-slide-btn-next")
    var itemClass = args.itemClass || "tkp-slide-item"; //each item container class to slide (default: "tkp-slide-item")
    var isAutoSlide = args.isAutoSlide || false;//set auto slide (default: false)
    var autoSlideTimer = args.autoSlideTimer || 2000;//set auto slide timer when isAutoSlide is true(default: 2000)
    var hideBtnNav = args.hideBtnNav || false; //hide button navigation(default: false)
    var isRandom = args.isRandom || false; //whether next or previous slide should be random index
    var slideIndex = args.startIndex || 0; //start slide index number (zero based, index 0 = slide number 1, default :0)


    var itemNodes = document.getElementsByClassName(itemClass);
    var itemLength = itemNodes.length;
    var autoSlideInterval;

    //public variable
    this.testParentVar = "parent var";

    //init function
    init();
    function init() {
        if (itemLength > 0) {
            showSlide();
            bindEvent();
            isAutoSlide ? setAutoSlide() : "";
            hideBtnNav ? setHideBtnNav() : "";
        } else {
            throw "Cannot find slider item class";
        }

    }


    //private function
    function showSlide() {
        if (slideIndex >= itemLength) { slideIndex = 0; }
        if (slideIndex < 0) { slideIndex = (itemLength - 1); }
        for (var i = 0; i < itemLength; i++) {
            itemNodes[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        itemNodes[slideIndex].style.display = "block";
    }

    function nextPrevSlide(n) {
        slideIndex += n;
        showSlide();
    }

    function bindEvent() {
        var btnPrevNode = document.getElementsByClassName(btnPrev);
        if (btnPrevNode.length > 0) {
            btnPrevNode[0].addEventListener("click", function () {

                if (isRandom) {
                    setRandomSlideIndex();
                } else {
                    nextPrevSlide(-1);
                }


                if (isAutoSlide) {
                    clearInterval(autoSlideInterval);
                    setAutoSlide();
                }
            });
        } else {
            throw "Cannot find button previous navigation";
        }

        var btnNextNode = document.getElementsByClassName(btnNext);
        if (btnNextNode.length > 0) {
            btnNextNode[0].addEventListener("click", function () {
                if (isRandom) {
                    setRandomSlideIndex();
                } else {
                    nextPrevSlide(1);
                }
                if (isAutoSlide) {
                    clearInterval(autoSlideInterval);
                    setAutoSlide();
                }
            });
        } else {
            throw "Cannot find button next navigation";
        }

    }

    function setAutoSlide() {
        autoSlideInterval = setInterval(function () {
            if (isRandom) {
                setRandomSlideIndex();
            } else {
                nextPrevSlide(1);
            }

        }, autoSlideTimer);
    }

    function setHideBtnNav() {
        document.getElementsByClassName(btnPrev)[0].style.display = "none";
        document.getElementsByClassName(btnNext)[0].style.display = "none";
    }

    function setRandomSlideIndex() {
        var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * itemLength);
        if (randomIndex == slideIndex) {
            setRandomSlideIndex();
        } else {
            slideIndex = randomIndex;
            showSlide();
        }
    }

    //public function
    this.nextPrevSlide = function (n) {
        nextPrevSlide(n);
        //console.log("nextPrevSlide");
    };

    //getter setter
    this.setItemClass = function (prm) {
        itemClass = prm;
    };
    this.getItemClass = function () {
        return itemClass;
    };


};

//Adding touch swiper
TkpSlider.prototype = function () {
    var self = this;
    var touchStartCoords = { 'x': -1, 'y': -1 }, // X and Y coordinates on mousedown or touchstart events.
        touchEndCoords = { 'x': -1, 'y': -1 },// X and Y coordinates on mouseup or touchend events.
        direction = 'undefined',// Swipe direction
        minDistanceXAxis = 30,// Min distance on mousemove or touchmove on the X axis
        maxDistanceYAxis = 30,// Max distance on mousemove or touchmove on the Y axis
        maxAllowedTime = 1000,// Max allowed time between swipeStart and swipeEnd
        startTime = 0,// Time on swipeStart
        elapsedTime = 0,// Elapsed time between swipeStart and swipeEnd
        //targetElement = document.getElementById('el'), // Element to delegate
        targetElements = self.getItemClass()
        ;

    init();
    function init() {
       
        addMultipleListeners(targetElements, 'mousedown touchstart', swipeStart);
        addMultipleListeners(targetElements, 'mousemove touchmove', swipeMove);
        addMultipleListeners(targetElements, 'mouseup touchend', swipeEnd);
    }

    function swipeStart(e) {
        e = e ? e : window.event;
        e = ('changedTouches' in e) ? e.changedTouches[0] : e;
        touchStartCoords = { 'x': e.pageX, 'y': e.pageY };
        startTime = new Date().getTime();
        //targetElement.textContent = " ";
    }

    function swipeMove(e) {
        e = e ? e : window.event;
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    function swipeEnd(e) {
        e = e ? e : window.event;
        e = ('changedTouches' in e) ? e.changedTouches[0] : e;
        touchEndCoords = { 'x': e.pageX - touchStartCoords.x, 'y': e.pageY - touchStartCoords.y };
        elapsedTime = new Date().getTime() - startTime;
        if (elapsedTime <= maxAllowedTime) {
            if (Math.abs(touchEndCoords.x) >= minDistanceXAxis && Math.abs(touchEndCoords.y) <= maxDistanceYAxis) {
                direction = (touchEndCoords.x < 0) ? 'left' : 'right';
                switch (direction) {
                    case 'left':
                        //targetElement.textContent = "Left swipe detected";
                        console.log("swipe left");
                        self.nextPrevSlide(1);

                        break;
                    case 'right':
                        // targetElement.textContent = "Right swipe detected";
                        console.log("swipe right");
                        self.nextPrevSlide(-1);

                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function addMultipleListeners(el, s, fn) {
        var evts = s.split(' ');
        var elLength = el.length;
        for (var i = 0, iLen = evts.length; i < iLen; i++) {
            if (elLength > 1) {
                for (var j = 0; j < elLength; j++) {
                    el[j].addEventListener(evts[i], fn, false);
                }
            } else {
                el.addEventListener(evts[i], fn, false);
            }

        }
    }
}();

var mainSwiper = new TkpSlider();
```

```css
.tkp-slide {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative; }
  .tkp-slide .tkp-slide-item:not(:first-child) {
    display: none; }
    .tkp-slide .tkp-slide-item img {
      width: 100%; }
  .tkp-slide .tkp-slide-btn {
    color: #fff !important;
    background-color: #000 !important;
    border: none;
    display: inline-block;
    outline: 0;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    white-space: nowrap;
    opacity: 0.7; }
    .tkp-slide .tkp-slide-btn:hover {
      background-color: #333 !important; }
  .tkp-slide .tkp-slide-btn-prev {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0%;
    transform: translate(0%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(0%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(0%, -50%); }
    .tkp-slide .tkp-slide-btn-next {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      right: 0%;
      transform: translate(0%, -50%);
      -ms-transform: translate(0%, -50%); }
```

```html
<section class="main-slide">
  <div class="tkp-slide tkp-slide--container">
    <div class="tkp-slide-item">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x200/f2d9f2/080708&text=1" alt="Slide 1" />
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="tkp-slide-item">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x200/f2d9f2/080708&text=2" alt="Slide 2" />
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="tkp-slide-item">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x200/f2d9f2/080708&text=3" alt="Slide 3" />
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="tkp-slide-item">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x200/f2d9f2/080708&text=4" alt="Slide 4" />
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="tkp-slide-item">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x200/f2d9f2/080708&text=5" alt="Slide 5" />
      </a>
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li class="tkp-slide-btn tkp-slide-btn-prev">
        &#10094;
      </li>
      <li class="tkp-slide-btn tkp-slide-btn-next">
        &#10095;
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I realize that the jsfiddle2 does not work on firefox when swipe left /right

Comment: I understand that this is an exercise but i think you are making it more complicated than needed. I just the otherday created a touch swipe handler to abstract all that. It is called GoodTap and you can get it with npm. It is also OO in that it is a class so even if it is more than you want, maybe it can help out. It is TS code but the es6 transpilation should be very close.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Problem 1:** You are not returning anything from the prototype function. You have to return each public method as properties of the return Object.

```
return {
  initSwiper : init,
  method1 : method1,
  method2 : method2,
};
```

**Problem 2:** You need to set variables inside the init function. Outside it **this** variable won't refer to TkpSlider.

```
    // init();
    function init() {
        self=this;
        var targetElements = document.getElementsByClassName(this.getItemClass());
        addMultipleListeners(targetElements, 'mousedown touchstart', swipeStart);
        addMultipleListeners(targetElements, 'mousemove touchmove', swipeMove);
        addMultipleListeners(targetElements, 'mouseup touchend', swipeEnd);
        return this;
    }
```

**Problem 3** You need to manually call the **initSwiper()** method to get your variables initialized when you create the TkpSlider Object.

```
var mainSwiper = new TkpSlider().initSwiper();
```

Then it will work  as you need and you can call public methods if you need.

```
mainSwiper.method1();
mainSwiper.method2();
```

**Working Snippet:**

```js
var TkpSlider = function(args) {
  args = args || {};
  //private variable
  var btnPrev = args.btnPrev || "tkp-slide-btn-prev"; //class for previous button (default: "tkp-slide-btn-prev")
  var btnNext = args.btnNext || "tkp-slide-btn-next"; //class for next button (default: "tkp-slide-btn-next")
  var itemClass = args.itemClass || "tkp-slide-item"; //each item container class to slide (default: "tkp-slide-item")
  var isAutoSlide = args.isAutoSlide || false; //set auto slide (default: false)
  var autoSlideTimer = args.autoSlideTimer || 2000; //set auto slide timer when isAutoSlide is true(default: 2000)
  var hideBtnNav = args.hideBtnNav || false; //hide button navigation(default: false)
  var isRandom = args.isRandom || false; //whether next or previous slide should be random index
  var slideIndex = args.startIndex || 0; //start slide index number (zero based, index 0 = slide number 1, default :0)


  var itemNodes = document.getElementsByClassName(itemClass);
  var itemLength = itemNodes.length;
  var autoSlideInterval;

  //public variable
  this.testParentVar = "parent var";

  //init function
  init();

  function init() {
    if (itemLength > 0) {
      showSlide();
      bindEvent();
      isAutoSlide ? setAutoSlide() : "";
      hideBtnNav ? setHideBtnNav() : "";
    } else {
      throw "Cannot find slider item class";
    }

  }


  //private function
  function showSlide() {
    if (slideIndex >= itemLength) {
      slideIndex = 0;
    }
    if (slideIndex < 0) {
      slideIndex = (itemLength - 1);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < itemLength; i++) {
      itemNodes[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    itemNodes[slideIndex].style.display = "block";
  }

  function nextPrevSlide(n) {
    slideIndex += n;
    showSlide();
  }

  function bindEvent() {
    var btnPrevNode = document.getElementsByClassName(btnPrev);
    if (btnPrevNode.length > 0) {
      btnPrevNode[0].addEventListener("click", function() {

        if (isRandom) {
          setRandomSlideIndex();
        } else {
          nextPrevSlide(-1);
        }


        if (isAutoSlide) {
          clearInterval(autoSlideInterval);
          setAutoSlide();
        }
      });
    } else {
      throw "Cannot find button previous navigation";
    }

    var btnNextNode = document.getElementsByClassName(btnNext);
    if (btnNextNode.length > 0) {
      btnNextNode[0].addEventListener("click", function() {
        if (isRandom) {
          setRandomSlideIndex();
        } else {
          nextPrevSlide(1);
        }
        if (isAutoSlide) {
          clearInterval(autoSlideInterval);
          setAutoSlide();
        }
      });
    } else {
      throw "Cannot find button next navigation";
    }

  }

  function setAutoSlide() {
    autoSlideInterval = setInterval(function() {
      if (isRandom) {
        setRandomSlideIndex();
      } else {
        nextPrevSlide(1);
      }

    }, autoSlideTimer);
  }

  function setHideBtnNav() {
    document.getElementsByClassName(btnPrev)[0].style.display = "none";
    document.getElementsByClassName(btnNext)[0].style.display = "none";
  }

  function setRandomSlideIndex() {
    var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * itemLength);
    if (randomIndex == slideIndex) {
      setRandomSlideIndex();
    } else {
      slideIndex = randomIndex;
      showSlide();
    }
  }

  //public function
  this.nextPrevSlide = function(n) {
    nextPrevSlide(n);
    //console.log("nextPrevSlide");
  };

  //getter setter
  this.setItemClass = function(prm) {
    itemClass = prm;
  };
  this.getItemClass = function() {
    return itemClass;
  };


};

//Adding touch swiper
TkpSlider.prototype = function() {
  var self;
  var touchStartCoords = {
      'x': -1,
      'y': -1
    }, // X and Y coordinates on mousedown or touchstart events.
    touchEndCoords = {
      'x': -1,
      'y': -1
    }, // X and Y coordinates on mouseup or touchend events.
    direction = 'undefined', // Swipe direction
    minDistanceXAxis = 30, // Min distance on mousemove or touchmove on the X axis
    maxDistanceYAxis = 30, // Max distance on mousemove or touchmove on the Y axis
    maxAllowedTime = 1000, // Max allowed time between swipeStart and swipeEnd
    startTime = 0, // Time on swipeStart
    elapsedTime = 0, // Elapsed time between swipeStart and swipeEnd
    //targetElement = document.getElementById('el'), // Element to delegate
    targetElements; //this.prototype.getItemClass()
  ;

  //    init();
  function initSwiper() {
    self = this;
    var targetElements = document.getElementsByClassName(this.getItemClass());
    addMultipleListeners(targetElements, 'mousedown touchstart', swipeStart);
    addMultipleListeners(targetElements, 'mousemove touchmove', swipeMove);
    addMultipleListeners(targetElements, 'mouseup touchend', swipeEnd);
    return this;
  }

  function swipeStart(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e = e ? e : window.event;
    e = ('changedTouches' in e) ? e.changedTouches[0] : e;
    touchStartCoords = {
      'x': e.pageX,
      'y': e.pageY
    };
    startTime = new Date().getTime();
    //targetElement.textContent = " ";
  }

  function swipeMove(e) {
    e = e ? e : window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  function swipeEnd(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e = e ? e : window.event;
    e = ('changedTouches' in e) ? e.changedTouches[0] : e;
    touchEndCoords = {
      'x': e.pageX - touchStartCoords.x,
      'y': e.pageY - touchStartCoords.y
    };
    elapsedTime = new Date().getTime() - startTime;
    if (elapsedTime <= maxAllowedTime) {
      if (Math.abs(touchEndCoords.x) >= minDistanceXAxis && Math.abs(touchEndCoords.y) <= maxDistanceYAxis) {
        direction = (touchEndCoords.x < 0) ? 'left' : 'right';
        switch (direction) {
          case 'left':
            //targetElement.textContent = "Left swipe detected";
            console.log("swipe left");
            self.nextPrevSlide(1);

            break;
          case 'right':
            // targetElement.textContent = "Right swipe detected";
            console.log("swipe right");
            self.nextPrevSlide(-1);

            break;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  function addMultipleListeners(el, s, fn) {
    var evts = s.split(' ');
    var elLength = el.length;
    for (var i = 0, iLen = evts.length; i < iLen; i++) {
      if (elLength > 1) {
        for (var j = 0; j < elLength; j++) {
          el[j].addEventListener(evts[i], fn, false);
        }
      } else {
        el.addEventListener(evts[i], fn, false);
      }

    }
  }
  return {
    initSwiper: initSwiper
  };
}();

var mainSwiper = new TkpSlider().initSwiper();
```

```css
.tkp-slide {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.tkp-slide .tkp-slide-item:not(:first-child) {
  display: none;
}

.tkp-slide .tkp-slide-item img {
  width: 100%;
}

.tkp-slide .tkp-slide-btn {
  color: #fff !important;
  background-color: #000 !important;
  border: none;
  display: inline-block;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  white-space: nowrap;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.tkp-slide .tkp-slide-btn:hover {
  background-color: #333 !important;
}

.tkp-slide .tkp-slide-btn-prev {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0%;
  transform: translate(0%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(0%, -50%);
}

.tkp-slide .tkp-slide-btn-next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0%;
  transform: translate(0%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(0%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<section class="main-slide">
  <div class="tkp-slide tkp-slide--container">
    <div class="tkp-slide-item">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x200/f2d9f2/080708&text=1" alt="Slide 1" />
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="tkp-slide-item">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x200/f2d9f2/080708&text=2" alt="Slide 2" />
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="tkp-slide-item">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x200/f2d9f2/080708&text=3" alt="Slide 3" />
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="tkp-slide-item">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x200/f2d9f2/080708&text=4" alt="Slide 4" />
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="tkp-slide-item">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x200/f2d9f2/080708&text=5" alt="Slide 5" />
      </a>
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li class="tkp-slide-btn tkp-slide-btn-prev">
        &#10094;
      </li>
      <li class="tkp-slide-btn tkp-slide-btn-next">
        &#10095;
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```

> Prototype confusion: which ***this*** is ***this***?

```
TkpSlider.prototype = function() {

  console.log(this); /* this this is Child */
  init();

  function init() {
    console.log(this); /* this this is Child, called from child context */
  }

  function initSwiper() {
    console.log(this); /* this this is Parent, called from parent context */
  }

  function swipeStartEventHandler(event) {
    console.log(this); /* this this is HTML element #customId*/
  }

  return {
    initSwiper: initSwiper,
  };
}();

new TkpSlider().initSwiper();
```

Comment: @Ardeus check the fixed working jsFiddle and let me know of any problem.

Comment: I guess your answer is fine, so once if I use prototype, the function scope is not longer behave like the Base class (can be called within function class whether it is public or private). As for firefox fix, I put the update here: https://jsfiddle.net/88L0k35t/1/

Comment: @Ardeus, Updated firefox fix and added explanations

Comment: thanks, I am curious, is it possible to call child function from parent using the above prototype?

Comment: Yes, just call it this.method_name() but you need to return this method as a property of the return object of the prototype as i described in the answer.